# How to check which host a php MongoClient is reading from?

Tags: php, mongodb, replication

I think this should be pretty basic, but I couldn't find it in the php docs, maybe I didn't look hard enough.

How would I determine the host that the MongoClient/MongoDB/MongoCollection/MongoCursor is actually connected to?  My connection string has a csv of the master and the slaves, and I expect that it is working fine, however I just want some verification.

Something like $db->getHost() or something like that, so I can add a debug hook to my queries and get a feel for how reads are being distributed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but try something along the lines of:
`$db->command(array('serverStatus'=>1));`

returning array like:

```
    "host" : "<hostname>",
    "version" : "<version>",
    "process" : "<mongod|mongos>",
    "pid" : <num>,
    "uptime" : <num>,
    "uptimeMillis" : <num>,
    "uptimeEstimate" : <num>,
    "localTime" : ISODate(""),
```

May need some playing about... ref:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/server-status/#server-status-example-instance-information

and:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.command.php

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an easy way for you to know which exact connection the driver is using.
It has plenty of logic to switch between connections depending on latency and read preferences for example.

The best way to achieve this is by using the Stream Notification interface.
That interface gives you pretty powerful way of debugging and logging your operations.
This was introduced in 1.4.0, although its still not documented (sorry!)
The [Original Pull Request](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/pull/349) describes the prototype of the individual operations you can hook listeneres into on the stream context, and the [test cases](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/pull/349/files#diff-10) hopefully give a better overview of its capabilities.

This interface will also be improved in the upcoming 1.5.0 series with all [sorts of goodies based around these stream](http://bjori.blogspot.com/2013/09/query-logging-and-profiling-in-mongodb.html).